# wso2 store getting error when testing Get method of api in store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am new to wso2. I have registered an api to wso2 publisher. I have subscribed to the api. I have generated the oauth keys. I go to the api under the apis, select the API Console, select the Get method, place the parameter value in the field and hit the "Try it Now" button and I get:

```
Request URL

http://172.31.4.135:8282/cdrSearch/1.0.0/cdr/search?q=test

Response Body

{
  "timestamp": 1431716819352,
  "status": 406,
  "error": "Not Acceptable",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException",
  "message": "Could not find acceptable representation"
}

Response Code

406

Response Headers

{
  "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: This error thrown from the backend itself since it may expecting a different mediatype and the request sent by API gateway has different mediatype. How you directly call your backend service? Is it a GET or a POST request?

Comment: I am just using the WSO2 Store to test the when I go to the API Console tab. I run the test under the "Get" section.

Comment: were you able to try the request with some other rest client ?